# Is there any way to trace\log the sql using Dapper?

Tags: dapper

Is there a way to dump the generated sql to the Debug log or something? I'm using it in a winforms solution so the mini-profiler idea won't work for me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I got the same issue and implemented some code after doing some search but having no ready-to-use stuff. There is a package on nuget [MiniProfiler.Integrations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.Integrations/) I would like to share.

**Update V2**: it supports to work with other database servers, for MySQL it requires to have [MiniProfiler.Integrations.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.Integrations.MySql/)

Below are steps to work with SQL Server:

1.Instantiate the connection

```
var factory = new SqlServerDbConnectionFactory(_connectionString);
using (var connection = ProfiledDbConnectionFactory.New(factory, CustomDbProfiler.Current))
{
 // your code
}
```

2.After all works done, write all commands to a file if you want

```
File.WriteAllText("SqlScripts.txt", CustomDbProfiler.Current.ProfilerContext.GetCommands());
```

Comment: Yes, there is a repository on github https://github.com/vndevpro/MiniProfiler.Integrations

Comment: Brilliant. You might want to change the project site to that github in the nuget - currently it seems to point to itself (or a previous version)

Comment: @hazjack - Sorry! I just realized the typo. I meant "too bad MySql isn't supported by MiniProfiler". As your solution only works for Sql Server.

Comment: I think MiniProfile accepts an abstract db connection, so just instantiate a connection for MySQL then it should work

Comment: Is that System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory in the example? Can't seem to find the "New" extension method or another implementation of SqlConnectionFactory. Is this example specific to a particular version of MiniProfiler.Integrations?

Comment: @Silverfox, the class is particularly in MiniProfiler.Integrations and was changed to DbConnectionFactoryHelper in V2.0 to not being confused :) I will update the answer with usage on lastest version. Tks for remark ;)

Comment: Worked like a dream for MySql.. Figured out my problem in 10 minutes. Changed to CustomDbProfiler.Current.ProfilerContext.GetCommands(). Thanks!

Comment: It works but is there anyway to remove the parameterized sql statements for this?

Comment: Is this answer valid for Net Core? `CustomDbProfiler.Current.ProfilerContext` is missing for me.

Comment: @daniherrera Take a look on this, it's available: https://github.com/vndevpro/MiniProfiler.Integrations/tree/master/MiniProfiler.Integrations.TestAppCore

Comment: While using SQL server and dapper, profiler.GetCommands() is returning nothing in catch block after the call to _dbConnection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(insertQuery, entity, transaction: null);

Answer (score 18):

Dapper does not currently have an instrumentation point here. This is perhaps due, as you note, to the fact that we (as the authors) use mini-profiler to handle this. However, if it helps, the core parts of mini-profiler are actually designed to be architecture neutral, and I know of other people using it with winforms, wpf, wcf, etc - which would give you access to the profiling / tracing connection wrapper.

In theory, it would be perfectly possible to add some blanket capture-point, but I'm concerned about two things:

- (primarily) security: since dapper doesn't have a concept of a context, it would be *really really* easy for malign code to attach quietly to sniff all sql traffic that goes via dapper; I really don't like the sound of that (this isn't an issue with the "decorator" approach, as the caller owns the connection, hence the logging context)
- (secondary) performance: but... in truth, it is hard to say that a simple delegate-check (which would presumably be `null` in most cases) would have much impact

Of course, the other thing you could do is: steal the connection wrapper code from mini-profiler, and replace the profiler-context stuff with just: `Debug.WriteLine` etc.

Comment: Hi Mark, could you give an example of the kind of attack you're worried about?

Answer (score 9):

You should consider using SQL profiler located in the menu of *SQL Management Studio* ***→ Extras → SQL Server Profiler*** (no Dapper extensions needed - may work with other RDBMS when they got a SQL profiler tool too).

Then, start a new session.

You'll get something like this for example (you see all parameters and the complete SQL string):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Updates WHERE CAST(Product_ID as VARCHAR(50)) = @appId AND (Blocked IS NULL OR Blocked = 0) 
                    AND (Beta IS NULL OR Beta = 0 OR @includeBeta = 1) AND (LangCode IS NULL OR LangCode IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@langCode, '','')))',N'@appId nvarchar(4000),@includeBeta bit,@langCode nvarchar(4000)',@appId=N'fea5b0a7-1da6-4394-b8c8-05e7cb979161',@includeBeta=0,@langCode=N'de'
```

Comment: There are some problems with this aproach, 1) if the DB is a common one (many processes and users in a test environment, for example), could be hard to filter the desired queries. 2) Azure Sql (and probably other DBMS) would not allow to connect using a profiler tool.

Comment: @zameb: You can filter by client ID (application name) and other properties, no problem. If you have enabled TCP connections to your SQL-Server and enabled access in your firewall, you can connect to your virtual SQL Server instance on Azure!

Answer (score 9):

### Try [Dapper.Logging](https://github.com/hryz/Dapper.Logging/tree/71f4f3de06b95f131e84171698e0d3ed7cb52f83).

You can get it from NuGet.  The way it works is you pass your code that creates your actual database connection into a factory that creates wrapped connections.  Whenever a wrapped connection is opened or closed or you run a query against it, it will be logged.  You can configure the logging message templates and other settings like whether SQL parameters are saved.  Elapsed time is also saved.

In my opinion, the only downside is that the documentation is sparse, but I think that's just because it's a new project (as of this writing).  I had to dig through the repo for a bit to understand it and to get it configured to my liking, but now it's working great.

From the documentation:

> The tool consists of simple decorators for the `DbConnection` and
> `DbCommand` which track the execution time and write messages to the
> `ILogger<T>`. The `ILogger<T>` can be handled by any logging framework
> (e.g. Serilog). The result is similar to the default EF Core logging
> behavior.
>
> The lib declares a helper method for registering the
> `IDbConnectionFactory` in the IoC container. The connection factory is
> SQL Provider agnostic. That's why you have to specify the real factory
> method:
>
> ```
> services.AddDbConnectionFactory(prv => new SqlConnection(conStr));
> ```
>
> After registration, the `IDbConnectionFactory` can be injected into
> classes that need a SQL connection.
>
> ```
> private readonly IDbConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
> public GetProductsHandler(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
> {
>     _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
> }
> ```
>
> The `IDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection` will return a decorated
> version that logs the activity.
>
> ```
> using (DbConnection db = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
> {
>     //...
> }
> ```

Comment: The "Gotcha" to this is when you are trying to understand a legacy codebase that has literally thousands of places where the SQL connections are created, and all slightly difference, so there is no viable way to make the changes...

Only something that is completely transparent to the existing code (except for a single place hook initialization at startuup) would be feasible. And yes, I do understand the security concerns...

Answer (score 6):

This is not exhaustive and is essentially a bit of hack, but if you have your SQL and you want to initialize your parameters, it's useful for basic debugging. Set up this extension method, then call it anywhere as desired.

```
public static class DapperExtensions
{
    public static string ArgsAsSql(this DynamicParameters args)
    {
        if (args is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(args));
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var name in args.ParameterNames)
        {
            var pValue = args.Get<dynamic>(name);

            var type = pValue.GetType();

            if (type == typeof(DateTime))
            sb.AppendFormat("DECLARE @{0} DATETIME ='{1}'\n", name, pValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
            else if (type == typeof(bool))
                sb.AppendFormat("DECLARE @{0} BIT = {1}\n", name, (bool)pValue ? 1 : 0);
            else if (type == typeof(int))
                sb.AppendFormat("DECLARE @{0} INT = {1}\n", name, pValue);
            else if (type == typeof(List<int>))
                sb.AppendFormat("-- REPLACE @{0} IN SQL: ({1})\n", name, string.Join(",", (List<int>)pValue));
            else
                sb.AppendFormat("DECLARE @{0} NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{1}'\n", name, pValue.ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can then just use this in the immediate or watch windows to grab the SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add an update here since I see this question still get's quite a few hits - these days I use either [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) (seems it's dead now) or [Stackify Prefix](https://stackify.com/prefix/) which both have sql command trace capabilities.

It's not exactly what I was looking for when I asked the original question but solve the same problem.

Comment: Glimpse not dead?

Comment: @Kiquenet huh so it seems - haven't used it in quite a while so I never noticed. It's a shame - it was really good.