# Dapper InsertAsync<T> not inserting records

Tags: dapper, dapper-extensions

Here is the top of the POCO I am using to create an object to install into my database table called "LOCITEMS":

```
[Table ("LOCITEMS")]
public class LOCITEMS :ICloneable
{
    [ExplicitKey]
    public string LOCATIONID { get; set; }

    public string SITE_ID { get; set; }
    [ExplicitKey]
    public string ASCITEMID { get; set; }

    public string ITEMID { get; set; }
    [ExplicitKey]
    public string SKIDID { get; set; }

    public decimal QTYTOTAL { get; set; }
    ...
```

And here is the code I am using to insert the record into that table:

```
private async Task<bool>InsertNewLocItem(LOCITEMS item, IDbConnection conn,  IDbTransaction trans )
    {
        if(item != null)
        {
           try
            {
                var x = await conn.InsertAsync<LOCITEMS>(item,trans);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When I check the var x it is always 0 and no record is getting inserted into my table.  This is part of a transaction, and the transaction is committing, but the record is not showing up.  I Added the "ExplicitKey" on the composite key columns for the table per other suggestions, but I am still not getting an insert, nor am I getting any errors in the "catch" either.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are not receiving an error I would suggest viewing the generated SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18529965/670028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up running a SQL Trace from SSMS and was able to intercept the sql statements.  Digging into the statements I found that one of the POCO fields was a string instead of a DateTime and was causing problems.  I changed the field type and re-ran it and it inserted.  I don't know why it wasn't throwing an error on the mismatch.